# How to maintain a view state record across custom controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

Having all sorts of trouble with what should be simple - I hope!

Assume you have a simple VF page to use as a lead registration form.  You instantiate a new lead record and can bind input fields via apex:inputField tags and all is wonderful in the world...

Now, you want to drop a custom component into the page, passing in the context lead record so that you can manipulate fields on the lead record directly.  I understand by using assignTo I can pass in a reference to the lead record from the main page controller, but so far unable to prove out that I can update fields from within the custom component controller and then see them passed through on lead submission.  Its the binding changes back onto the main controller record that is causing me heartburn.

Any pointers most appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Ok - found the discussion about controller extensions to facilitate communications. See http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Controller_Component_Communication

CH out!

Comment: another example solution can be found in the book Visualforce Development Cookbook, chapter 2 'Updating attributes in component controllers'